# Log file for JNLP application - Need suggestion

Tags: java, jnlp

I'm developing a Java Swing application and enabled them with Java web start feature.

Currently, i'm logging the events in a log file and saving them in jre folder.

Is this a correct way of doing?

If not where can i save the log files?

Note : i've asked the same question in other forum, but unable to get any suggestions.

Comment: `System.getProperty("user.home")` can be used to store logs or some sub folder.

Comment: The jre folder is the wrong place to do it. As assylias suggested the user.home directory is a better place. If your application has its own directory then store it there.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to store the log files in `System.getProperty("user.home")`.